# Fast Fourier Transform for Harmonic Analysis

Tags: python, numpy, fft, guitar

I'm analyzing the harmonics present in the wave motion as a function of where along the string the pluck occurs.  I hope to obtain a plot like those exhibited on this page: https://softwaredevelopmentperestroika.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/fast-fourier-transforms-with-python-the-noise-and-the-signal/.  To do this, I've written code modelling an asymmetric triangle and implemented numpy's fft.  The data being output, however, is not what I expect, and it's peaked about a frequency of 0 Hz.  Here is my code and its output:

```
from numpy.fft import fft as npfft, fftfreq as npfftfreq
#triangular pulse
def triangular_pulse(x, xmean, sigma):
    for i in x:
        if x[i]<=xmean:
            y[i] = x[i]*(sigma/xmean)
        else :
            y[i] = sigma-(x[i]-xmean)*(sigma/(200-xmean))
    return y

N_masses = 200
T  = 0.0669264714
mu = .03937
cSq = T/mu
c  = np.sqrt(cSq)
dx = 1.0

dt = dx/c
print dt

#Initialize some arrays
x0  = np.arange(N_masses)*dx
y   = np.zeros(N_masses)
vy  = np.zeros(N_masses)
ay  = np.zeros(N_masses)

#Set Initial conditions (pluck)
# # half-pluck
# y = 30*gaussian_pulse(x0,x0[N_masses/2],2)

# quarter-pluck
y = triangular_pulse(x0,x0[N_masses/4],1)

rhat=npfft(y)
freaq=npfftfreq(len(y),dt)
plt.plot(freaq,np.abs(rhat)/len(rhat))
plt.show()
```

Please let me know if you spot the source of my problem.  Thanks!

## Update

Added
    y = triangular_pulse(x0,x0[N_masses/40],1)
    y-=np.mean(y)
with the result of a broader non-zero band; peak is still centered around "0", however.

Comment: with the suggested change, the peak is NOT centered at 0. At 0 the abs of the fft is 0. You have 2 peaks at very low frequencies, one positive and one negative, on the 2 sides of 0. Compare carefully the 2 plots, obtained with and without the line `y-=y.mean()`

Answer (score 2):

Just subtract the mean of the signal before running the frequency analysis, i.e. after calling `triangular_pulse`:

```
y-=y.mean()
```

and you will obtain the peak at a non-zero frequency. This is because the signal has a mean component that is not zero, that will show up as the component at zero frequency.

EDIT: as a comment, you can rewrite the triangular pulse function using numpy [where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
def triangular_pulse2(x,xmean,sigma):
    return where(x<xmean,x*sigma/xmean,sigma-(x-xmean)*(sigma/(200-xmean)))
```